# Is travel insurance only for when we go to outside country by Air or it can be also in within country?

Tags: insurance, india, life-insurance, travel

Is travel insurance only for when we go to outside country by Air or it can be also in within country?

What is the benefit of Travel Insurance if I'm already having Life and Health Insurance?

Is health insurance not valid from outside country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Life Insurance is valid anywhere in the world irrespective of where you stay or where you die.

Medical insurance on the other hand is bound by geography. IE general medical policies issued in India are valid only within India for treatment. So you can develop the condition anywhere, but you need to be treated in India in order to get cover under the policy. This is because the premium charged is less as the medical expenses in India are less say compared to US or Europe.

Hence if you are travelling outside India you need to take a seperate Overseas Travel Insurance that covers;
 - Medical Cover
 - Loss of Luggage due to Transit
 - Delayed flights etc

So the policy is in effect from the time you cross Indian Immegration. It is irrespective of the mode of travel.

I do not think in India we have a regular Travel Insurance for domestic travel.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, read the fine print to the life and health insurance you have and to the travel insurance you consider - YMMV greatly and the last thing you want is being not covered when you expected coverage.

Usually the travel insurance covers both the flight and being in the foreign country with the exception of high risk activities like diving and others - you have to pay extra to have incidents happened during those activities covered. You may be able to purchase the insurance for the flight only - where I live there're policies issued by the railway that cover incidents that might happen while the person is in railway transit, so I guess there's similar stuff for flights. Again, read the fine print carefully.

There're two reasons for having separate travel insurance.

First, many people don't have health insurance either because they're careless or because they believe they can pay cash in case they need care. Prices abroad can be much higher than what they got used to in their country, so they prefer to buy travel insurance.

Second, your health insurance may be valid abroad (read the fine print and ask the company though), but it might happen that you insurance company while being good in your country will not be able to arrange giving you care abroad - they won't have an agreement with clinics in the country you go to or will be unable to speak that country language when needed or whatever else. If you seriously consider relying on your policy abroad - ask lots of questions and try to get independent reviews.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the UK.  All of the travel policies that I have had cover me for vacations taken both in the UK or overseas.  The definition used is that they must be trips to pre-booked accommodation lasting at least one night.  This usually covers me for cancellation/delay to any transport that I use (train/ferry) loss of belongings, cancellation due to illness of myself or close relative.

You need to look at the specific terms of the insurance contract that you are buying.  In the UK this sort of policy is normal.  In India it may well not be.